# Drupal 7 Field Performance

Tags: 7, entities, performance

I've created a Content Type that will have >50 fields. I've noticed that each field has a corresponding table. Is Drupal joining 50 tables in order to load the page with all of the designated content?

Would a high amount (but not an unnecessary) amount of fields cause a noticeable decrease in performance?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer really depends on your database backend. If you're using something like MySQL 5.6 or MariaDB 5.5 I would say probably not http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/04/04/join-optimizations-in-mysql-5-6-and-mariadb-5-5/. If you're using a different database backend, it will be hard to tell without testing.

If using something like [MongoDB](http://cyrve.com/mongodb) for the field backend then it shouldn't cause any performance issues.

If you don't want to go with MongoDB or bleeding edge MySQL you can also look into using something like the [Entity Cache](http://drupal.org/project/entitycache) if you find that all the fields is causing performance issues.